# How to map elements of the list to their indices using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Having a list of strings, I need to construct a list of objects which are effectively pairs `(string, its position in the list)`. Currently I have such code using google collections:

```
public Robots(List<String> names) {
    ImmutableList.Builder<Robot> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        builder.add(new Robot(i, names.get(i)));
    }
    this.list = builder.build();
}
```

I would like to do this using Java 8 streams. If there was no index, I could just do:

```
public Robots(List<String> names) {
    this.list = names.stream()
            .map(Robot::new) // no index here
            .collect(collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toList(),
                    Collections::unmodifiableList
            ));
}
```

To get the index, I would have to do something like this:

```
public Robots(List<String> names) {
    AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger(0);
    this.list = names.stream()
            .map(string -> new Robot(integer.getAndIncrement(), string))
            .collect(collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toList(),
                    Collections::unmodifiableList
            ));
}
```

However, the documentation says that mapping function should be stateless, but the `AtomicInteger` is effectively its state.

Is there a way to map elements of the sequential stream to their positions in the stream?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public Robots(List<String> names) {
    this.list = IntStream.range(0, names.size())
                         .mapToObj(i -> new Robot(i, names.get(i)))
                         .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));
}
```

However it may not be as efficient depending on the underlying implementation of the list. You could grab an iterator from the `IntStream`; then calling `next()` in the `mapToObj`.

As an alternative, the [proton-pack](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack) library defines the `zipWithIndex` functionality for streams:

```
 this.list = StreamUtils.zipWithIndex(names.stream())
                        .map(i -> new Robot(i.getIndex(), i.getValue()))
                        .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));
```

Comment: If I was using `next()` from `Iterator` in the mapping function, it would be stateful. `zipWithIndex` looks interesting - it doesn't use list directly so it will work with any stream. Thanks!

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Yes that is true. And yes if the underlying list is a `LinkedList` for example; you'll get bad performances. The `zipWithIndex` returns a Stream with `Long` indices; if you really need `Integer` ones, you can use the zip method by providing a (potentially) infinite `IntStream` :-)

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to stream indices:

```
List<Robot> robots = IntStream.range(0, names.size())
                              .mapToObj(i -> new Robot(i, names.get(i))
                              .collect(toList());
```