# How to convert List<DataObject> to Map<Integer, String> using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects. I want to do the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < sorted.size(); i++) {
    map.put(i, sorted.get(i).getName());
}
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in Java 8 streams api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Map<Integer, String> map =
        IntStream.range(0, sorted.size())
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(toMap(i -> i, i -> sorted.get(i).getName()));
```

This creates a Stream of `int` going from 0 to the size of list and collects each value into a Map.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i was hoping for something more like sorted.stream().blah(....)

Comment: You can't stream a list with its indexes, unfortunately, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28989841/1743880

Comment: @dinesh707, `EntryStream.of(sorted).mapValues(s -> s.getName()).toMap()` using [my free library](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) if you really want not to think about indices. In general Tunaki solution is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to collect the elements into a data structure which intrinsically tracks the position as its size, you can do the operation using a custom collector:

```
Map<Integer, String> map=sorted.stream()
    .map(x -> x.getName())
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m,s) -> m.put(m.size(), s),
        (a,b) -> { int off=a.size(); b.forEach((i,s) -> a.put(i+off, s));});
```

The trickiest part is the merge function which will be used in parallel processing only. It adds all elements of a map to its preceding map, but has to offset the keys by the number of preceding elements.