# How to fully sort 2d array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, 2d

I want to sort 2d array in java. 
For example
Suppose I have this matrix

```
1    5    4
3    7    8
2    9    6
```

After sorting, result should be like

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
```

Please help me with this.

I have written following code for this problem

```
class Sort2dArrayFull{
public static void sort(int el[][]){
    int m=0;
    int n=0;
    int temp=0;
    int k1=1;

    for(int i=0; i<el.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<el[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(el[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    System.out.print("\n");

    for(int i=0; i<el.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<el[i].length; j++){
            for(int k=j+1; k<el[m+n].length; k++){
                if(el[i][j]>el[m+n][k1]){

                    temp=el[i][j];
                    el[i][j]=el[m+n][k1];
                    el[m+n][k1]=temp;

                }

                k1++;

                if(k1==el[m+n].length){
                    k1=0;
                }
                if(k==el[m+n].length){
                    m++;

                }

                if(m==el.length){
                    m=0;
                    n++;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<el.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<el[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(el[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
public static void main(String... args){
    sort(new int[][]{{1,5,7,2},{55,44,11,77,33},{15,19,16,14,12,13}});
}
```

}

And the output of this program is

//before sorting

1 5 7 2

55 44 11 77 33

15 19 16 14 12 13

//after sorting

19 15 44 55

1 7 5 77 33

2 11 16 14 12 13

But i want result like this

1  2  5  7

11 12 13 14 15

16 19 33 44 55 77

Comment: Please try something and then ask.

Comment: SO does not do your homework for you.

Comment: Try making use of 
`java.util.Arrays.sort` and override the `compare` method in the  `java.util.Comparator`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: @Dhammika: I don't think that will work, because you not only need to re-arrange the arrays of the first dimension, but also shuffle stuff around in the second dimension. A comparator is not supposed to change any of its inputs.

Comment: This will be a lot easier if you treat this as a one-dimensional array (either by actually copying it into one such, or by using some coordinate mapping function).

Comment: @Thilo : There won't be a direct implementation, but sorting first and then re-building the array. If got another way of doing, pls share. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If I were u, I'll do as follows:

```
public static void sort(int el[][]){
    for(int i=0; i<el.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<el[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(el[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayToSort = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int x = 0; x < el.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < el[x].length; y++)
        {
            arrayToSort.add(el[x][y]);
        }
    }
    Integer[] sortedArray = new Integer[arrayToSort.size()];
    sortedArray = arrayToSort.toArray(sortedArray);
    Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
    int sequence = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < el.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < el[x].length; y++)
        {
            el[x][y] = sortedArray[sequence++];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nAfter:");
    for(int i=0; i<el.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<el[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(el[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could get rid of the intermediate list and write directly into the `sortedArray` (which could be an `int[]` instead of an `Integer[]`)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. But it is not working. :(

Comment: What do u mean it's not working? It's sorted properly in my workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You could **try** to get marks presenting this to your professor :)

```
    Integer[][] a = {{1, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 8}, {2, 9, 6}};
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sortedAndGrouped =
            Arrays.stream(a)
                    .flatMap(l -> Arrays.stream(l))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> i.getAndIncrement() / a.length));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
            IntStream.range(0, a.length)
                    .mapToObj(r -> sortedAndGrouped.get(r))
                    .toArray()));
```

Comment: You could get rid of the AtomicInteger and go streaming all the way with some kind of `zipWithIndex`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989841/how-to-map-elements-of-the-list-to-their-indices-using-java-8-streams