# What's a more functional way in Java 8 of updating items in a list with their index?

Tags: java-8, functional-programming

Given:

```
  static class Item {
    String name;
    int index;

    Item(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    List<Item> items =
        Arrays.stream(new String[] {"z", "y", "x"})
          .map(Item::new)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    items.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.name));

    // begin functionalize me    
    int i = 0;
    for (Item it : items) {
      it.index = i++;
    }
    // end functionalize me

    assertEquals(0, items.get(0).index);
    assertEquals(1, items.get(1).index);
    assertEquals(2, items.get(2).index);
  }
```

What is a more functional way in Java 8 of writing the code between the "functionalize me" comments?  I was considering a strategy using reduce or collect, but can't quite see the solution in my head.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to map elements of the list to their indices using Java 8 streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989841/how-to-map-elements-of-the-list-to-their-indices-using-java-8-streams)

Answer (score 3):

You should not assume the list returned by `Collectors.toList()` to be mutable. Hence, you must not call `sort` on it. In your  specific case, you can just sort before collecting:

```
List<Item> items = Stream.of("z", "y", "x")
  .map(Item::new)
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.name))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or, since `name` is identical to the incoming string:

```
List<Item> items = Stream.of("z", "y", "x")
  .sorted()
  .map(Item::new)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then, you can update the list items using

```
IntStream.range(0, items.size()).forEach(i -> items.get(i).index = i);
```